# Rails 3: Render differently if email is opened on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I have an email which renders perfectly on a standard machine. However, when a user opens the email on their iphone there is a gray box that suddenly enlarges and takes up more space than it normally should. Is there a hack that I can use in order to have my html.erb page recognize whether or not it is being rendered in an iphone and adjust itself accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically the CSS you would have to modify in general.

Follow [this link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) showing which styles etc. are supported on iphone devices and which are not..

Answer (score 0):

In order to get user's browser information, there is a cool gem called `Browser`. I strongly recommend you to check out [its repo on Github](https://github.com/fnando/browser).

Once you install this gem,

```
browser.mobile?
```

will give you `true` or `false` and you'll be able to do whatever you want depending on the answer.